# Grouped cross correlation using long data frames, subsetting by row values

Tags: r, correlation

### What I want to do

I have a data frame of simultaneous observations of a value at multiple sites. These observations are repeated at multiple times (think of a group of weather stations, all measuring temperature on the hour, every day for a year).

I'd like to get the correlations between the measured values at each site, subset by month. I'm particularly interested in getting R-squared. So, that's R-squared for site 1: site 2, site 1: site 3, etc, for January, February, March, etc.

### The story so far

Let's fake some data:

```
df <- data.frame("B" = c(rep("January",20),rep("February",20)),
                 "D" = c(seq(1,20,1),seq(1,20,1)),
                 "site1" = c(seq(1,20,1),seq(0.1,2,0.1)),
                 "site2" = c(seq(2,40,2),seq(0.2,4,0.2)),
                 "site3" = c(seq(3,60,3),seq(0.3,6,0.3)))
```

now, because we have a large number of sites (and we don't know how many pretty much until run time), let's melt these into a long data.frame:

```
require(reshape)
df.melt <- melt(data = df,
                id.vars = c("B","D"),
                values = c("site1","site2","site3"))
```

### Where I get stuck

I figured i'd try the `nlme` package. I start by creating a `groupedData` object:

```
require(nlme)
df.melt.grp <- groupedData(value ~ value | variable,
                           data = df.melt,
                           inner = ~ B)
```

I think what I'm saying here is consider `value` to be dependent on `value`, grouped by `variable` (which is the site, after the melt), and then further subset by the month.

Then I try to apply `lmlist` to get the regression

```
lm.model <- lmList(object = df.melt.grp)
```

Unfortunately, when I ask for the summary of this, it looks as though I'm not getting the cross-correlations or subsetting by month:

```
> summary(lm.model)
Call:
  Model: value ~ value | variable 
   Data: df.melt.grp 

Coefficients:
   (Intercept) 
      Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
site1    5.775   2.163481 2.669309 8.680907e-03
site2   11.550   2.163481 5.338618 4.658854e-07
site3   17.325   2.163481 8.007927 9.612311e-13

Residual standard error: 13.68306 on 117 degrees of freedom
```

### Question

How do I get the correlations (measured using r-squared) between measurements at different sites, month-by-month, without resorting to a bunch of "for" loops?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what it means to compare month1 to month 2. How exactly are we supposed to use a correlation coefficient to compare January (31 days) with February (28 days)? Or if you meant only within a single month, then how are you supposed to set up the 1-1 relationship between site values that is need for a correlation coefficient calculation?

Comment: I want correlations between all of the data from station 1 with station 2, station 2 with station 3, and station 3 with station 1 in January, then the correlations between the stations for February, March, etc. I would use the `D` column to do the alignment I guess. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hmisc library includes the `rcorr` function that will take a matrix argument

```
require(Hmisc)
 lapply(split(df[, 3:5], df$B),
              function(mo) rcorr(as.matrix(mo))[[1]]^2 )
$February
      site1 site2 site3
site1     1     1     1
site2     1     1     1
site3     1     1     1

$January
      site1 site2 site3
site1     1     1     1
site2     1     1     1
site3     1     1     1
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea except would it work when I don't know the number of columns of `df` a priori?

Comment: No problem. You can use `df[ , grep("site")]` as the argument to `split`.

Comment: I suppose that's one way to do it. Unfortunately the site names are never as straightforward as the example data, so I'll have to fiddle. If no-one else suggests anything in the next few days, I might accept this. Thanks!

Comment: In any case you will need to offer a specific rule for picking columns to be considered. You implicitly did so when you offered your `melt` argument `values=c("site1","site2","site3")`.